# 80s/90s movie scene where tentacles grab and pull person through bath drain

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

There is a movie that I am trying to look for and the scene that I remember most was a scene where a teenage girl was taking a bath in a old bathtub without a showerhead and what looked like to be octopus tentacles coming from the drain and grabbing the girl and attempting to pull her down the drain and it ended up being a dream when she woke up.

I don't know if it would be consider sci-fi or fantasy, but I hope that it is and that I can be able to get this question answered like any question I ask, if I can.

Comment: Hmmm, are you sure it was octopus tentacles and not Freddy Kreuger's glove? There is a scene just like this in "A Nightmare on Elm Street". Was there actually an octopus creature in the film? Another possibility is "The Blob" where a guy gets pulled down a sink drain, can't remember if there is a dream sequence in that one or not (don't think so).

Comment: Yes, it was tentacles but I don't remember if they were octopus tentacles, I just said that it looked like it. I am not sure if they are octopus tentacles or not, but they kinda looked like octopus tentacles. The scene also was in a bathroom in the bathtub and the tentacles were attempting to pull her in the drain. That's what I can remenber so far.

Comment: If it only looked like tentacles, it might have been giant spider legs, which in less-than-optimal lighting conditions, and being wet from coming out of the drain might have looked similar? Then it could have been Stephen King's "IT". I think there was a scene like this... Not sure though, so only a comment.

Comment: There is a similar scene in Roger Lovin (actually Rodgers Clemens)'s novel *The Presence* - unless I'm mixing it up with  Thomas and Wilhelm's *Clone*. A boy is assimilated by a blob and disappears down a drain (also in *Schlock Mercenary* webcomic - https://www.schlockmercenary.com/2008-02-24)

Comment: It wasn't Stephen King's "IT", but the Schlock Mercenary is the right example. I just remember that It was just in a old bathtub with no showerhead and I think the movie was with a mother, her teenage son and teenage daughter. But I don't remember anything else at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be [Drainiac!](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/1194787_drainiac?) (2000)

> Death rises up from the drain in director Bret Piper's inventive,
>   special effects-heavy horror yarn about an old dark house and a
>   vengeful water demon. As Julie Ashbrook and friends begin out an old
>   mansion that's scheduled to be restored, their work is frequently
>   interrupted by a series of strange occurrences involving water. Julie
>   believes that strange forces are at work within the dilapidated
>   estate, but her friends think she's losing her mind. By the time the
>   ancient water demon that inhabits these drain pipes manifests itself
>   in the flesh, Julie and her friends realize that their lives aren't
>   the only things at stake, because this demon wants to devour their
>   bodies and swallow their souls.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! While this may answer the question it is better to include the relevant details into your answer for why it matches the OPs description

Comment: Perfectly done by Valorum! Thank you!

Comment: Yes, this was the movie that I was looking for. Funny that it's from the late 90s or 2000 when it looks like something that was filmed in the late 80s or early 90s.